# How to edit a jface table which holds a list of string as the model

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created a table viewer with input as a `List<String>` with the default array-content provider, column label provider.

In addition to that I have added the EditingSupport for that column.

```
EditingSupport#setValue(java.lang.Object element, java.lang.Object value)
```

The problem am facing is not able to change the string contents after the cell is being edited. Using a default TextCellEditor.

In the function `setValue` the element and value are strings.
Can anyone provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to change the value of a `String` you will have to change the model used by your content provider to use a class which contains the string. You can then call methods of that class to set the new value.